# How to paginate with Vuetify and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Goodnight

I'm trying to do server side paging with Vuetify and Laravel.

But the methods provided by Vuetify have not worked for me to do it correctly. I have a completed page that I want to implement with the Vuetify components.

I attach my code made with simple bootstrap.

```
  <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item" v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
          <v-btn flat icon color="red lighten-2">
            <v-icon  @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1, search)">thumb_down</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item" v-for="page in pagesNumber" :key="page" :class="[page == isActived ? 'active' : '']">
            <v-btn fab dark color="indigo" @click.prevent="changePage(page, search)" v-text="page">
            </v-btn>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item" v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">             
          <v-btn flat icon color="red lighten-2">
            <v-icon  @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1, search)">thumb_down</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Method of page to server:

```
    methods:{
            get(page, search){
              let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles?page=${page}&search=${search}`;
              axios.get(url)
                  .then( response => {

                  let res = response.data
                  this.products = res.articles.data; 
                  this.pagination = res.pagination;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                })
            },
            changePage(page, search){
                this.pagination.current_page = page;
                this.get(page, search);
          },
 },
```

The previous code works correctly but without actually using the paging of the Vuetify component.

Using the Vuetify component for paging I only show the lentgh of the pagination but in no way I manage to pass between the pages provided by the server.

```
      <v-pagination
        v-model="pagination.current_page"
        :length="pagination.total"
        prev-icon="mdi-menu-left"
        next-icon="mdi-menu-right"
        @input="next"
      ></v-pagination>
```

Looking for information indicate that using **@input="next"** I can call a method to go to the next page **but what can I use to return?**

How can I click on any page number and ask for the page to the server as in my code made with bootstrap?

I wish I could help and I thank you.

Answer (score 23):

Here is what works for me with Laravel 5.5 and Vuetify 1.3:

---

**HTML**

```
<v-pagination
    v-model="pagination.current"
    :length="pagination.total"
    @input="onPageChange"
></v-pagination>
```

---

**JS**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: null,
            pagination: {
                current: 1,
                total: 0
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getUsers() {
            window.axios.get('/api/users?page=' + this.pagination.current)
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.data;
                    this.pagination.current = response.data.current_page;
                    this.pagination.total = response.data.last_page;
                });
        },
        onPageChange() {
            this.getUsers();
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUsers();
    }
}
```

---

**Laravel**

```
public function users()
{
    $users = User::paginate(10);

    return response($users, 200);
}
```

When your component is mounted, `getUsers()` will get called. `pagination.current` defaults to 1 so the first page will load. The response will set `pagination.total`. Vuetify handles binding the page buttons to `pagination.current` so that when you click one, `pagination.current` gets set to the page number and then `@input` triggers `getUsers()` which uses `pagination.current` to get the page you selected.

Note: in laravel 5.8, the pagination response object may have changed from `response.data.current_page` to `response.data.meta.current_page` and `response.data.last_page` to `response.data.meta.last_page`
.

Comment: detailed explanation helps a lot, and make things quick

Comment: Notice this is still working on `Laravel 6` and `Vuetify 2.1.7`

Comment: Works fine with Laravel 7.

Comment: this works for me in laravel 8 too.
now, where and how do i `v-for` -ing thing? i tried `v-for="(users, id) in users" :key="users+id"` but nothing shows up.

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi i recommend taking a look at the Vue documentation. `v-for="user in users" :key="user.id"` should work.